# How to eager load relationships on multiple levels?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have the following models:

ProductA - ProductB - Feature - Option

I have the following relations:

ProductA belongsToMany ProductB
ProductB belongsToMany Feature
Feature belongsToMany Option

When I want to see details of ProductA, (a post with ProductA id, that will be managed by a controller) I'd like to eager load all the relationships
to pass a variable containing all the details to the view.

Is it possible with a single Eloquent instruction?

Something like this (I know it's not working): is it the correct way?

```
$prodcutDetails = ProductA->with('product_b')->with('features')->with('option')->find($id);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dot notation to eager load relations of relations. Like so:

```
$prodcutDetails = ProductA::with(['product_b', 'product_b.features', 'product_b.features.option'])->find($id);
```

Comment: option is not directly related to product_b but to features

Answer (score 1):

@Jerodev gives a good answer above, but the multiple relations are redundant; using `$prodcutDetails = ProductA::with('product_b.features.option')->find($id);` would be more efficient and you still have access to `product_b` and `product_b.features`.